# WebAPI self host project doesn't bind to port when running as normal user

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, permissions, owin

When I run visual studio in an Owin instance via self hosting, it fails to bind to the port I give it in app.config.
When I run visual studio as Administrator everything works like expected, but I would like to avoid having to do that. Does anyone know a way to do this?

This is my app.config setting:
    `<add key="ListenPort" value="8181" />`

And this is the code that does the binding:

`_instance = WebApp.Start(_config.ListenAddress, webAppConfiguration.Configuration);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run this command from an admin command prompt it'll reserve that port for your user:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8181/ user=domain\user
```

If you don't know what your user should be you can run this from the command prompt:

```
whoami
```

Comment: Note that omitting the trailing slash after the port number will cause the command to fail with the following error message: `Url reservation add failed, Error: 87
The parameter is incorrect.`

Comment: Yes, that is possibly because you're reserving the fully qualified namespace not the port. For example you could reserve http://+:8181/myservice1/ and http://+:8181/myservice2/ for the same or separate users (which would mean you could only bind to those urls, not http://+:8181/ directly.)